# Whats wrong with firewall configuration with iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have below firewall configuration which is DROP/DENY by default but I am unable to browse any webpage what am I missing ? Note:- I have ens33 as interface and Ubuntu is the OS I m using.

```
root@ubuntu:~# iptables -L -n -v --line-number
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 360 packets, 33205 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      720 54133 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ens33  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
3        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ens33  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
4        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  ens33  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
5       28  4698 ACCEPT     udp  --  ens33  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53
6        5   420 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 4166 packets, 357K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1       28  1744 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      ens33   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
2        5   420 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
3        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      ens33   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
4        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      ens33   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace destination to source port or source port to destination port for 80 and 443 ports in INPUT and OUTPUT iptables chains.

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail though my problem is solved but strange thing is eventhough I do a iptables --flush still rules seems to be applied on browsing though iptables -L shows no rules that were there ....any idea?

Comment: It's depend of Linux OS version. Usually iptables is saved by command `service iptables stop` and when OS is going to shutdown. If you want to edit saved rules file, iptables service must be stopped.